# simple groovy operator question: Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)

Tags: grails, groovy

Can you tell me how the expression

```
Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
```

works?  It doesn't fit the groovy ternary if, so what special operator is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps breaking it up into two expressions would help.  `params.max ? params.int('max') : 10` is the ternary expression...the result of which ends up being the first arg to `Math.min` (with `100` being the other arg).

Looks like the end result is an integer that's limited to being at most 100, and defaults to 10.

Answer (score 15):

Is it clear now?

```
def max = params.max? params.int('max') : 10
Math.min(max, 100)
```

BTW this is a nice idiom popular in Grails - if the parameter `max` exists, read it, *but* if it exceeds given value (`100` by default), truncate it to `100`. This way an attacker or malignant user won't make your application to return arbitrary big amount of data from the database.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying the value of limiting this for site attackers.

Answer (score 0):

When protecting against attack, you may want to look at the bottom bounds as well. I just ran across this in grails 2.4.4: Anything less than 1 appears to return all records. It's not documented, and the source appears to check for values > -1, but I found I had to check values > 0:

```
 //Use value, if found, else 20
 int max = params.getInt('max') ?: 20

 //no less than 1, no more than 100: max < 1 returns ALL records (grails 2.4.4)
 max = Math.max(max, 1)
 max = Math.min(max, 100)

 Domain.list(max: max)
```